# Why do I not see inode data in a hexdump or dd?

Tags: files, filesystems, inode

I'm not quite familiar with filesystem layers in the Linux kernel but I suppose that `dd` and `hexdump` do not get the inode information since they only do `open()` and `read()` syscalls, but I might be horribly wrong. Maybe the inode information is even there in the hexdump and I just don't see it.

Comment: Which inode data do you want? There are easy ways to get much of the info in a standardized format (lstat) and harder ways to get the raw data from the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

**The inode data is not in the file**: If you open a file with a text editor and type `hello world`, then just these 11 bytes go into the file. One for each character (if character is ASCII, but maybe 2, 3, 4 or 5 bytes for other characters ☺). File size, permissions, times etc are in the inode. The inode is not in the file.

Use `stat` to look at the `inode`.

Answer (score 1):

What would you ultimately like to do?

If you `hexdump` or `dd` parts of the raw data at the block where the inodes resides then... well, `dd` and `hexdump` display that data...

Use `dumpe2fs /dev/<device> | less` to find where the inodes are stored.